# delay between hitting `ESC` (in insert mode) and switching to normal mode within `screen`

Tags: escape, gnu-screen

If I

1. open (vanilla) `vim` by running `$ vim [-u NONE]`,
2. switch to insert mode by pressing `a`,
3. add an 'a' by pressing `a` again,
4. switch back to normal mode by pressing `ESC`, and
5. repeat steps 2 and 4 several times,

I see my cursor switching from on top of the 'a' (normal mode) to after the 'a' (insert mode) and back instantly as I press the corresponding keys.

If I now

1. exit `vim` by typing `:q!` and confirming with `RETURN`/`ENTER`,
2. start a (vannilla) `screen` session by running `$ screen [-c /dev/null]`, and
3. repeat the above excercise,

the switch from normal to insert mode after pressing `a` is still instantly but there is a notable delay between me pressing `ESC` and `vim` switching back to normal mode.

I observed this with `Screen version 4.01.00devel (GNU)` and both, `VIM - Vi IMproved 7.4` and `NVIM 0.2.0-dev`

How can I configure `[n]vim`/`screen` to avoid this delay?

Comment: How do you determine whether there is a delay? Is that based on the cursor changing, on the bar at the bottom of the screen or your inability to type anything until insert mode starts?

Comment: @Octaviour: All three metrics show the delay. But note that it's not the inabilty to type until *insert* mode starts but until *normal* mode starts. The switch from normal to insert is fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the solution on http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/GNU_Screen_integration:

> ### Getting the Esc key to work
>
> ---
>
> If you use Vim under Screen, you might find that the `Esc` key doesn't work.
>   To fix this, add the following to your `.screenrc`:
>
> `> maptimeout 5`
>
> This may be necessary so Screen will wait no more than 5 milliseconds between characters when detecting an input sequence.